# Create stored procedure to modify row if it exist and insert new row into table if it doesnt

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

[image]

How can I create a stored procedure to update the Std_Course's column based on the Id and Name parameter, OR inserts a new row if the Id and Name does not exist

Comment: No need for a stored procedure, just use `MERGE`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that is **IF** he's on SQL Server **2008** or newer ... `MERGE` doesn't exist for 2000 or 2005 ....

Comment: @marc_s: if someone does not mention the version, I assume it's a current one.

Comment: yes, its SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_InsertOrUpdate
    @ID INT, @Name VARCHAR(50), @StdCourse INT
AS 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = @ID AND Name = @Name)

        UPDATE dbo.YourTable
        SET Std_course = @StdCourse
        WHERE ID = @ID AND Name = @Name

    ELSE    

        INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ID, Name, Std_Course)
        VALUES(@ID, @Name, @StdCourse
```

**Update:** since you're on SQL Server 2008, you could also use a simple `MERGE` statement - either directly "inline" or inside the stored procedure. It would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_InsertOrUpdate
    @ID INT, @Name VARCHAR(50), @StdCourse INT
AS 
    MERGE dbo.YourTable AS t
    USING (SELECT @ID, @Name, @StdCourse) AS Source(ID, NAME, Std_Course) 
    ON source.ID = t.ID AND source.Name = t.Name

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Std_Course = @StdCourse

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(ID, Name, Std_Course)
        VALUES(source.ID, source.Name, source.Std_Course);
```